# Bluemix Container Blocked but vulnerability assessment passes

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have a Bluemix IBM Container created that passes the Vulnerability Assessment but is still 'Blocked' when I try to use it to deploy into my organization.

[Passing Vulnerability Assessment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxRSR.png)

[Image Blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEWn8.png)

I don't know how to work around this.  Any ideas?  Is it a timing issue?  I've waited 2 hours, but it still is 'blocked'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for one of the default images? If yes which one? or is this a custom image you uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Since your container passes the Vulnerability Assessment but your image is still blocked I suggest you to open a support request directly from your Bluemix console using the support/help widget: in this way you'll involve IBM Containers support team in checking and fix this issue. They will be able to perform in-depth investigation of your error.

Please provide org and space guids and some details on the image you used (for example the Dockerfile if you have it).

You can retrieve org and space guids using CF CLI (when you already logged in):

```
cf org <orgname> --guid
cf space <spacename> --guid
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess , You can be overloaded your Container's Limit. That's why , It may be blocked you. How are your source statements ?